# Custom Equals Method in C#

Tags: c#

I wrote a class called `baseCommodity` and it includes a customized `Equals` method:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    BaseCommodity other = obj as BaseCommodity;
    return other != null && other.GetType() is this.GetType());
}
```

I want to compare the `other.GetType()` with the Type of `this` class but `is this.GetType()` does not work. I keep getting the error "Unexpected symbol `this', expecting`type'"

Comment: change 'is' to '==' and you're golden.

Comment: You just want to test if the types match in an equals operator?

Comment: hmm well ... first of all thank you all for the fast and good answers... 

I'm currently refactoring my code and thanks Ralf for your comment ... actually i think i don't need this anymore after my refactoring xD

Thank you guys! i've learned something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `==` instead:

```
return other != null && other.GetType() == this.GetType();
```

You can use `is` when the you know the compile time type token of the object which you can check against.

As a side note, if you're overriding `Equals(object other)`, perhaps you also want to implement [`IEquatable<BaseCommodity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and override it's `Equals(BaseCommodity other)` which saves you the type checking.

Also, this is a very *weak* type equality check.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit more info would be nice for an answer.

`GetType` returns a type *object*, not a *type token*. Type tokens are handled with `is`, type objects are compared using equality (==).

In other words:

```
object a = 12893;
if (a is int) // compare by token:
{ ... }
```

and

```
object a = 12345;
if (a.GetType() == typeof(int)) // compare by equality of type object.
{ ... }
```

PS: Equality can give strange results with inheritance. In this case you might want to use `SomeType.IsAssignableFrom` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you need the comparison operator `==` here.

`is` is a type check and it is used with a variable on the left and a **type** on the right:

```
string s = "";
bool isString = s is string;
```

Please note that the result of `GetType` is not a *type*, it is a *variable that represents a type*.